# How to create a file:/// link in Sharepoint?

Tags: hyperlink, file, external-data

If I include a file link in a desktop Word document, I am able to follow it, for example

[file:///C:/](https://file:///C:/)

or

[file:///K://my_confidential_network_folder](https://file:///K://my_confidential_network_folder)

In Sharepoint, the link is displayed as a link but I am not able to follow it (e.g. with Ctrl+Click). I expected that sharepoint would open the file uri in a new browser tab.

I also tried to use a single or double / in the uri:

- Single / opens a new tab but does not show the folder
- Double and tripple / do not react on click.

On the other hand, if I paste an uri in a browser address bar, it works when using double or tripple /. Single / does not work.

[image]

Instead of showing the file uri in a new browser tab, "nothing" happens from end user perspective. In the console there is an error

```
WordEditorDS.js:4697 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/
```

**=> How can I correctly include hyperlinks using the [file uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) instead of http scheme in Sharepoint?**

If that does not work, is there an alternative to link local network resources, so that Users with the corresponding access rights can easily follow them with a click?

Is there an option to specify that the uri should be openend in a new browser tab? Something like:

```
browser:ofv|u|file://C:/
```

(Unfortuntely, "browser" is not supported in the [office uri scheme](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/file-sharepoint-not-allowed-to-load-local-resources-file/m-p/876913).)

**Related:**

- https://help.metashare.com/en/faq/how-do-i-create-links-to-documents-using-office-uri-schemes/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/file-sharepoint-not-allowed-to-load-local-resources-file/m-p/876913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)** This is a restriction by the browsers; they do not allow to open the file link for security reasons.

It is possible to install a google chrome extension and a companion executable (requires admin rights) to open local links. However, expecting all end users to do so is not realistic.

It would also possible to start a webserver that hosts the local files. Also see related SO question for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/local-explorer-open-file/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl

**b)** As a workaround you can create a downloadable shortcut file for Windows:

file_link.url

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=file:///C:
```

and upload it to Sharepoint as a Document.

Also see related question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77707743/how-to-avoid-that-firefox-appends-download-to-name-of-downloaded-file

**c)** Some web part, that would at least allow users to **copy a file link to the clipboard** with a single click... so that they are able to paste it in the Windows File Explorer... would be nice. Unfortunately, the SharePoint CodeSnippet WebPart does not have a copy button. Therefore, one would need to implement a custom copy-to-clipboard WebPart. Also see

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Copy-text-to-user-clipboard-on-click-of-a-button/td-p/910009

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-create-copy-to-clipboard-on-sharepoint/ff34fed1-c94d-425a-b63b-60579cb48b3e

[Button on SPO Page that copies the URL of an item in a list view web part with a checkmark next to it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285107/button-on-spo-page-that-copies-the-url-of-an-item-in-a-list-view-web-part-with-a)